# Angular 2 formControl does not detect value changed programmatically

Tags: angular

I have very simple form (see below), and this is an issue:

- when I enter input value manually, form.controls['myValue'].value changes
- if I change #myInput value programmatically, it's totally ignoring that change

What am I doing wrong?

```ts
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `<form [formGroup]="form">
          Current value: {{form.controls['myValue'].value}}
          <input type="text" 
             size=40 
             id="myValue"
             name="myValue" 
             required
             [formControl]="form.controls['myValue']">

          <input type="button" (click)="updateValue()" value="Update">
        </form>`
    })
    export class AppComponent {

      form:FormGroup;

      constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
          myValue: new Date().toString()
        });
      }

      updateValue(){
        document.querySelector('#myValue').value = new Date().toString();
      }

    }
```

Comment: please make it as a plunker or fiddle

Comment: need your json.so update your post with the relevant json for **form.controls**

Comment: @CharanCherry here it is https://plnkr.co/edit/hQGn6nfl6pNkS1zfneEv?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

Form control, which attached to an input, detect changes by subscribing on 'input' event of HMLTInputElement, but in your case you change it directly from code, so the event not firing.

1. Try to use formControl setValue() method
2. Manually fire 'input' event via dispatchEvent() method

Comment: Thanks! It works: this.form.controls['myValue'].setValue(new Date().toString());  It's strange that I could not find explanation in Angular documentation and in Ng-Book, I think this post will help other developers

Comment: You maybe want to take a look at the documentation for [FormControl](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html) and keep in mind that programmatic changes to a control's value will **not** mark it `dirty`. If you want to achieve that you will need to call `markAsDirty()` on your control (which origins in the [AbstractControl](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/AbstractControl-class.html) class that FormControl extends)

Comment: Thanks, I see: programmatic change of text input value doesn't fire 'change' event (it's fired only on blur) - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/change

Comment: If I call markAsDirty on a control it still shows an old value for the control and not the current value :
        this.filtersFormGroup.controls['startDateTime'].markAsDirty();
        console.log('startDateTime after markAsDirty : ' + this.filtersFormGroup.controls['startDateTime'].value);

At what point are you supposed to call markAsDirty?